# Hexo NeXT Theme categories and tags page

Tags: github, blogs, hexo

I am starting a Hexo v4.2.0 | Theme - NeXT.Gemini v7.7.2. 
I really want to show the list of my categories and tags in menu.

Yes. I have activated "categories" and "tags" in the sidebar in _config.yml 
I have followed up to this point by referring to the documentation and other blogs.

```
menu:
  home: / || home
  #about: /about/ || user
  tags: /tags/ || tags
  categories: /categories/ || th
  archives: /archives/ || archive
  #schedule: /schedule/ || calendar
  #sitemap: /sitemap.xml || sitemap
  #commonweal: /404/ || heartbeat
```

Then, I created pages for categories and tags. The files sit in source/categories and source/tags.

categories/index.md

```
---
title:categories 
date:2020-03-15 09:28:47
type:categories
---
```

tags/index.md

```
---
title:All tags
date: {{date}}
type:tags 
---
```

No matter what I put into those index.md files for categories and tags, **The categories and tags in menu do not get activated.**

I currently have 3 categories and 20 tags. However, they do not get displayed in the categories page or tag page in the sidebar.

You might refer to the capture image and the link to my blog page below. 
(Apologies, it is written in Korean but there are tags and categories in the sidebar).

[sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tg5l.png)

my page is on github djangojeng-e.github.io

I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `tags/index.md` as:

```
---
title: tags
date: 2020-05-08 18:52:51
type: "tags"
---
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still coming up empty.  Here's my index.md

```
---
title: tags
date: 2020-12-06 12:07:32
type: "tags"
---
```